# Reloading a frame

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I am creating a class UIView which has a frame which loads a webview in it. When I click the link in the webview it opens up another webview with a back button . i would like to how can I make the back button event to reload the UIview .

Comment: Just to make this clear: You have a UIWebView inside a UIView inside a navigation controller. When the user taps a link in the UIWebView is a new UIWebView pushed to the navigation stack ? And you want to reload UIWebView 1 when the user comes back from the second screen ?

Comment: Yes I want to do that only , I am able to get the second UIWebview with a back button but not able to get what should I write in the back button function

Comment: I am not using navigation controller the main class is UIView

Comment: But why do you make a new UIWebView when the user taps a link? Just load the URL of the link in your existing web view.

Comment: Because I am showing up the back button only when the user goes to another webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use 2 UIWebView. The easiest way to implement a back button like in safari and other apps is to implement the UIWebViewDelegate Method. Inside this method you set the enabled property of your button to the canGoBack property of the web view.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
     backButton.enabled = webView.canGoBack;
}
```

When the web view stops loading the new website, the button gets enabled.

Another interessting property of the UIWebView is `canGoForward` for the forward button.

See the [UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details.